How to change the color of the statusBar/systemNavigationBar on IOS
whats the way to change the color of statusBar/systemNavigationBar on IOS?
I've tried these ways - both working on Android but not on IOS:
void main() async {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.orange.shade300,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
  );
}


and
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
    value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.orange.shade300,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
  );
}


Is this a problem of the iPhone Simulatior or do i need a different way?

The status bar color cannot be changed directly, as it depends on the color of the background below it. Therefore, you must adjust the status bar color via the AppBar color or the background color if it is transparent.
This is a way to change the color in iOS:
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.orange.shade300, // This has no effect on iOS
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark, 
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange.shade300, // Change status bar color through app bar color
          title: Text('Title'),
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


doesnt' work, sorry. The AppBar color is already set und backgroundcolor doesn't change anything (expect de body).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
